# What's wrong with my code? CS50 Pset2: Readability

Tags: c, logic, cs50, readability

1- I don't know what's wrong with my code, this is ## help ## **readability** CS50 pset2.
2- The problem seems to be in float grade (string grade) function.
3- I am a beginner and it's my second time coding in C so if I missed something important please tell me, or if you have any tips that make my code looks better, thank you!

```
   //Libraries
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    
    //Functions
    int count_letters(string letter);
    int count_words(string word);
    int count_sentences(string sentence);
    float grade(string grade);
    
    int main(void)
    {
        string par = get_string("text: ");
    }
    
    
    int count_letters(string letter)
    {
        int letters = 0;
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(letter); i < n; i++)
            {
                 if (isalpha(letter[i]))
                      letters++;
            } 
        return letters;
    }
    
    
    int count_words(string word)
    {
        int words = 1;
        int spaces = 0;
        int nword;
        nword = strlen(word);
        for (int i = 0; i < nword; i++)
            {
                 if (isspace(word[i]))
                      spaces++;
                      words = spaces + 1;
            }
        return words;
    }
    
    
    int count_sentences(string sentence)
    {
        int sentences = 0;
        int nsentence;
        nsentence = strlen(sentence);
        for (int i = 0; i < nsentence; i++)
            {
                 if (sentence[i] == '.' || sentence[i] == '!' || sentence[i] == '?')
                      sentences++;
            }
        return sentences;
    }
    
    
    float grade(string grade)
    {
        //here comes my problem. variables like letters, words, and sentences are "undeclared identifier"
     float x = 0.0588 * (100 * letters / words) - 0.296 * (100 * sentences / words) - 15.8;
                 if (x < 16 && x >= 0)
                    {
                      printf("Grade %i\n", (int) round(x));
                    }
                 else if (x >= 16)
                    {
                      printf("Grade 16+\n");
                    }
                 else
                    {
                      printf("Before Grade 1");
                    }
    }
```

Comment: CS50 is a C course. C and C++ are very different languages. Don't tag C++ if you're not asking about C++.

Comment: You need to read about variable scope in your favourite book.

Comment: Who is supposed to call all those functions? In `main` you do not call any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is - you haven't declared `letters`, `words`, or `sentences` in the `grade` function.

The declarations of those variables in other functions are *local* to those functions - they are not visible from within the `grade` function.

You have a couple of bigger issues, though.  For one thing, none of your functions are being *called* from anywhere - `main` reads a string and then immediately exits without doing anything else. For another, `grade` doesn't have a way of knowing what values should be in `letters`, `words`, or `sentences`.

What you *probably* want to do is call your counting functions from within `grade` like so:

```
float grade( string s )
{
  int letters = count_letters( s );
  int words = count_words( s );
  int sentences = count_sentences( s );

  float x = ...;
  ...
}
```

and then call `grade` from `main` as

```
int main( void )
{
  string par = get_string( "Text: " );
  grade( par );
}
```

Alternately, you could call each of the counting functions from `main` and pass the results as *arguments* to `grade`:

```
int main( void )
{
  string par = get_string( "Text: " );

  int letters = count_letters( par );
  int words = count_words( par );
  int sentences = count_sentences( par );

  grade( letters, words, sentences );
}
```

in which case both the declaration and definition of `grade` should be

```
float grade( int, int, int ); // declaration

float grade( int letters, int words, int sentences ) // definition
{                                                    // since they are declared as arguments,
  float x = ...;                                     // there's no need to declare them in the body of the function
}
```

Now, here's a question - do you intend for anyone to use the value of `x` after `grade` exits?  If so, then you need to add a

```
return x;
```

to the end of `grade`.

If not, then change the function's return type from `float` to `void` in both the declaration and definition:

```
void grade( string ); 

void grade( string s ) { ... } // definition
```